# Why don't we use a short integer to represent a return value?

Tags: c, types, return

So many books say we must never waste a bit for arithmetic and function definitions. I saw so many small numbers from 0 to 255 that were defined as char type variables, with even larger positive numbers defined as an unsigned short int type.

Why don't we use an unsigned short int or a char type instead of int to represent a return value?

I tried:

```
char main(){return 0;}
```

It is ok.

Comment: "So many books say we must never waste a bit..." What books say that? That's not a true statement.

Comment: Your functions can return whatever you feel like, but not `main()`. That one returns `int` because that's how the C standard specifies it.

Comment: The standard specifically requires `main` to return an `int` (slight oversimplification), so that's what the calling environment expects. You can use a `char` return type for functions other than `main` if you like, but it's not going to help significantly.

Comment: Besides as far as I know, in hardware level you can never effectively fetch just 1 byte from memory, so there's really no performance benefit in saving bytes. Compilers will even impose a 4-byte alignment to variables to improve performance, because it's better to have garbage between variables than having to fetch data from two separate addresses just because the variable address wasn't aligned.

Comment: @KeithThompson: On 8 bit MCUs it is common practice.

Comment: @John Kugelman: But it is a ture statement. Maybe you never read those books, but they do exists. I don't know how to translate those name into english. if you can find them, try search '谭浩强C语言入门'，‘30天C算法速成’，‘C语言数据结构与算法’，‘C编程高手’，'51单片机C编程' etc.... I can sure those books told about this(opinion).

Comment: @Havenard: Please help me where to learn C standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is very seldom any savings involved in returning a `short` or even a `char` in preference to an `int`. In the vast majority of C implementations, a machine register will be used to hold the return value, and the only difference in returning a `short` instead of an `int` is that part of the register will remain unused. (As an aside, this is also the reason why a `main` returning a `char` "works" for you, even though the standard doesn't guarantee that it will.)

Virtually the only reason, then, for returning a `short` is when you have a particular algorithm that has distinct reasons for working with `short`s instead of `int`s, and that's just not very common.

For the record, the same thing can be said of function arguments as well.

Comment: And to add, if I understand correctly, you have an additional clock-tick or two used in the implicit conversion from `int` to whatever smaller data choice you use, so you are incurring the cost of an implicit conversion from the default `int` in addition to the partial use of a register.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Not sure where you might have gotten that idea. There *may* be costs involved in casts, but that's not really what we were talking about, is it? (And there are many situations in which even those are free, perhaps even a majority.)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: On second thought, I guess you're talking about the partial-register stalls on Intel CPUs. Even so, though, that is, if anything, only a problem in casts, not as long as you keep using the same values as `short`s., which I believe is what we're talking about here.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Also, on third thought, I'm fairly sure those partial-register stalls even only occur when recombining register parts (like, for instance, when you have an `EAX` with non-zero upper-16 bits, write to `AX`, `AL` or `AH`, and then read from `EAX` again -- it is that last operation which requires a recombining µop). I'm fairly sure there are no extra penalties for simply reading from a partial register or for doing sign-/zero-extensions.

Comment: That must be what I'm thinking of. I recall a discussion before, here on S.O. regarding the compiler handling of `short` and `char` as opposed to `int` and the whether it was the cast (which is what sticks in my mind as the implicit conversion) or the handling the upper 16-bits in `EAX` after 8-bit or 16-bit operations, I can't say for certain. (I wish I could find the thread). I'll drop a link back when I put my hands on in.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: You can see Agner Fog's [µarch guide](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf) for more info (sections 6.8, 7.13, 8.11, 9.11, &c.). Either way, I'm fairly sure it shouldn't affect what is being discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

If you learned something about assembly language and principles of microcomputer, you will know that, it's the fast way (one cycle) to access data.

For 32-bit or 64-bit CPU, one instruction cycle can get/set 32-bit or 64-bit data.
If a variable is defined as int, CPU can get/set its value by one cycle. If using char or short for 32-bit CPU, CPU needs more cycle to get/set its value.

It will be different if you are working on a 8-bit or 16-bit CPU. But normally the length of int is same with the CPU's bit, so integer is the fast type to access.

Comment: *"If using char or short for 32-bit CPU, CPU needs more cycle to get/set its value."* -- That is rarely true. The vast majority of modern CPUs will work with 8-, 16-, 32- or 64-bit numbers with the exact same speed. The only real-world exception I can think of would be pre-BWX Alpha processors, and I think the number of people working with those are... small.

Comment: Did you ever check the assembly code of DSP or ARM? Do you know how DSP or ARM optimizes their code?  For example, it will turn char to integer for access speed while optimization.

Comment: Admittedly I don't all that much about DSP code (but that also sounds fairly esoteric for a general answer), but I'm curious what operations you speak of on ARM. Where are you saying there are any particular performance hits for working with `short`s or `char`s over `int`s? I, for one, haven't found any particular cases.